# Set Case Feed Default Email Address

Tags: email, service-cloud-console

I am using the service console to handle cases that come in via email. We're using feed view. The "From" email address currently defaults to the user's individual email address, and then they can select an organization wide email addresses. I want to set one of the organization wide email addresses as the default. I'm ideally looking for a declarative way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a built in way to accomplish this that doesn't require any code.

1. Setup > Customize > Cases > Page Layouts
2. Click "Edit" on the layout that is a feed-based layout.
3. Select "Feed View", just underneath the home bar.
4. Here there exists a setting named "Specify From Address(es)". Activate it and choose whichever email address you want as default.

This works great if you are only setting a few email address as the default for everyone. This does not allow you to automatically set the "From" email address based on any criteria. To do that you would need a programmatic solution.